# How to compute this double integral involving the gamma function?

Tags: calculus, special-functions

Assuming that $a > 0,\ {\tt Mathematica}$ says that
$$\!\!\!
2\int_{0}^{\infty}\!\!\!\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{v^{a}\,\left(u + v\right)^{a - 1}\,\,
\mathrm{e}^{-u -2 v}}{\Gamma^{2}\left(a\right)} \,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v =
a - \frac{\Gamma\left(a + 1/2\right)}{\Gamma\left(1/2\right)\Gamma\left(a\right)}.$$

How can we arrive at the solution $?$.
I don't see the proper change(s) of variables.

---

Note: $\displaystyle\Gamma\left(a\right) =
\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{a - 1}\,\,\mathrm{e}^{-t}
\,\mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: Given the form of the right hand side and your integrand, I am inclined to think there is a little bit of beta function fun in here. Perusing the wikipedia article for the beta function might yield some insight...

Comment: The fraction of the three gamma functions also appears in Legendre's duplication formula, this might be useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{2\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{v^{a}\pars{u + v}^{a - 1}\,
\expo{-u - 2v} \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{a}}\dd u\,\dd v}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{a}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{v}^{\infty}
v^{a}\expo{-v}u^{a - 1}\,\expo{-u}\,\,\dd u\,\dd v
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{a}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\
\underbrace{\bracks{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{\ic k\pars{u - v}} \over k - \ic 0^{+}}{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}}}
_{\ds{\Theta\pars{u - v}}}\ \times
\\[2mm] &\
v^{a}\expo{-v}u^{a - 1}\,\expo{-u}\,\,\dd u\,\dd v
\end{align}
$\ds{\Theta}$ is the *Heaviside Theta*
( or *Heaviside Step* ) *Function*.

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{2\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{v^{a}\pars{u + v}^{a - 1}\,
\expo{-u - 2v} \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{a}}\dd u\,\dd v}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{a}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{1 \over k - \ic 0^{+}}
\underbrace{\bracks{\int_{0}^{\infty}v^{a}
\expo{-\pars{1 + \ic k}v}\,\,\dd v}}
_{\ds{\pars{1 + \ic k}^{-a - 1}\,\,\Gamma\pars{a + 1}}}
\ \times
\\[2mm] &\
\underbrace{\bracks{\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{a - 1}
\expo{-\pars{1 - \ic k}u}\,\,\dd u}}
_{\ds{\pars{1 - \ic k}^{-a}\,\,\Gamma\pars{a}}}
{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{a}}\,\Gamma\pars{a + 1}
\Gamma\pars{a}\ \times
\\[2mm] &\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\pars{1 + \ic k}^{-a - 1}\,\,\pars{1 - \ic k}^{-a} \over
k - \ic 0^{+}}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
2a\left[%
\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\pars{1 + k^{2}}^{-a}\,\pars{1 + \ic k}^{-1} \over k}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}\right.
\\[2mm] &\
\left.+
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\pars{1 + k^{2}}^{-a}\,\pars{1 + \ic k}^{-1}
\bracks{\ic\pi\,\delta\pars{k}}{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}\right]
\\[5mm] = &\
2a\int_{0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{1 + k^{2}}^{a}\,k}
\pars{{1 \over 1 + \ic k} - {1 \over 1 - \ic k}}
\,{\dd k \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[2mm] &\
+ a
\\[5mm] = &\
a - {2a \over \pi}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd k \over \pars{1 + k^{2}}^{a + 1}}}
_{\ds{\root{\pi}\Gamma\pars{a + 1/2} \over 2\Gamma\pars{a + 1}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{a - {\Gamma\pars{a + 1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1/2}\Gamma\pars{a}}}\quad
\pars{\substack{\mbox{Note that}\\[1mm]
\ds{\root{\pi} = \Gamma\pars{1 \over 2}}}}\\ &
\end{align}

---

The last integral can be evaluated with
Ramanujan's Master Theorem. Namely,
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\dd k \over \pars{1 + k^{2}}^{a + 1}} =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{k^{\color{red}{1/2} - 1} \over
\pars{1 + k}^{a + 1}}\,\dd k
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&{1 \over \pars{1 + k}^{a + 1}} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-a - 1 \choose n}k^{n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{a + n \choose n}
\pars{-1}^{n}k^{n} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\color{red}{\Gamma\pars{a + 1 + n} \over \Gamma\pars{a + 1}}{\pars{-k}^{n} \over n!}
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\dd k \over \pars{1 + k^{2}}^{a + 1}} =
{1 \over 2}\Gamma\pars{1 \over 2}\,
{\Gamma\pars{a + 1 - 1/2} \over
\Gamma\pars{a + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &
\root{\pi}\Gamma\pars{a + 1/2} \over 2\Gamma\pars{a + 1}
\end{align}